# What kind of flower?

Tags: identification

it resends itself every year in Florida. Looks like a giant zinnia but leaves are all wrong for that. Very bushy, tall plant. Thanks[image]

Comment: What are the leaves like? Do you have a pic?

Comment: And how tall is it?

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely Cosmos sulphureus, but the leaves of your plant are not in focus so hard to be 100% sure, although what can be seen suggests it's that. This link shows a particular variety of the plant https://www.gardenia.net/plant/cosmos-sulphureus-cosmic-yellow and one of the images shows the leaves clearly.